# mysqlsh rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage force prompt

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

From mysqlsh I can run this instruction:

```
...
shell.connect(host, pass);
dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage(clusterName);
```

But then it's asking me (y|N answer) for each instance it finds offline whether or not I want to turn it on again.

In the context of scripting this instruction (automation), how can I ignore these prompts and force y(es) for all of them?

Comment: `yes` - https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=linux+yes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `rejoinInstances` option to specify all my nodes, and it seems that doing it that way the shell doesn't ask for confirmation:

```
dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage(clusterName, {rejoinInstances: ["node-2:3306","node-3:3306"]});
```

Note: don't include the seed in the array.